# FFMpeg video clipping

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to use the ffmpeg apis (not the command line) for clipping videos to a specific size (e.g say 1hr video, create a new video starting at 10 minutes and ending at 30 minutes). Are there any examples of doing this out there?

I have used the apis to stream and record video so I have a bit of background knowledge.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the command line tool?

Comment: Because I am using the libraries for my application.

Comment: I was asking because what you want to do is as simple as 'ffmpeg -ss starttime -t duration' from cmd line. The exe itself is only 50-60 kb overhead if you build ffmpeg with shared libraries.

Answer (score 0):

`ffmpeg` (the command line tool) is just a frontend to the APIs with some extras. The whole source of the `ffmpeg` CLI tool is contained in one single source file `ffmpeg.c`. I suggest you just take a look into that to see, how ffmpeg does it internally.

Comment: I have been looking there, an explained example would however make things easier.